# Mapping Previous/Next track keys with IntelliType driver with Microsoft Natural Keyboard 4000

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm using the Microsoft Natural Keyboard 4000 set with Mac OS X 10.9.
I'd like to figure out how to map the next/previous track keys (mostly for Spotify) from the MacBook Pro's keyboard onto the keyboard's sepecial keys like 1,2,3,4,5. (The volume and play/pause keys work just fine).
Is that possible, and any helpful tips?
Failing a good way of setting this up, I'll settle for a more generic keyboard mapper from function keys to next/prev track keys (Is KeyRemapForMacbook the goto thing for that?).
Thanks!
-k